# Share image and text data on facebook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook

i want to share image and text data on facebook i did not want the facebook Compose view all the sharing is done by clicking the button on the view how it will be possible?

Comment: i havee no idea i can do it using the facebook compose view but i want to do it without using the composer view all things should be done in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the Facebook API, without showing the iOS Facebook viewer.  Take a look at the Facebook iOS SDK Docs.  You will obviously need the user to approve your app with the correct permissions, which means a FB Session will be open.

The plus with using the stock iOS FB Dialog is that you do not need to use the Facebook SDK and the user doesn't need to grant your app permission.  If you are not using Facebook Sessions in your app, you have to stick with the comment dialogue that iOS provides, there isn't a way around that per facebook.

```
-(void) postImageToFB:(UIImage *) image
{

    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
    Facebook* fb = [(uploadPicAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook   ];

    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[fb accessToken],@"access_token",
                                    @"message text", @"message",
                                    imageData, @"source",
                                    nil];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" 
                   andParams:params 
               andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                 andDelegate:self];


}
```

Comment: Need a little more than that.  What isn't working.  Is it throwing an error?  Are you properly incorporating the newest version of the Facebook SDK?  Do you have an open FB Session within the app?  Has the user appropriately approved publish permissions?